# How to create text effect like copyright protected image in shutterstock.com using Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

While searching google, we see a lot of images with a text overlay effect that claim these images are coming from shutterstock.com.

This text effect is something like the following:

https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/4187557/559982074/stock-vector-few-little-houses-in-the-winter-forest-landscape-flat-style-vector-seamless-pattern-559982074.jpg

I am wondering how can I use ImageMagick cli to do something similar?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I need to add similar effect to protect our drawings, because our drawings were stolen, their search rank is good in Google Images, but not linking to our website.

Shutterstock effect is good because 

1. it can protect drawing in different color style ( light or dark), and it has a big X to protect whole picture.

2. When you have to position a lot of drawings together, it won't make them looking ugly.

So, how to make the big X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi fmw42, thank you :) How can I add a big X like shutterstock.com?

Draw two diagonal lines between the corners.

Input (tile_aqua_500.jpg) :

[image]

In Imagemagick 6 Unix system:

```
infile="tile_aqua_500.jpg"
ww=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:w-1]" info:)
hh=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:h-1]" info:)
convert "$infile" \
-fill "graya(100%,0.75)" \
-draw "line 0,0 $ww,$hh line $ww,0 0,$hh" -alpha off \
-fill "graya(50%,0.25)" \
-strokewidth 1 -stroke "graya(100%,0.25)" \
-gravity center -font arial -pointsize 48 \
-annotate +0+0 "Hello World" tile_aqua_500_text_x.jpg
```

In Imagemagick 7 Unix system:

```
infile="tile_aqua_500.jpg"
magick "$infile" \
-fill "graya(100%,0.75)" \
-draw "line 0,0 %[fx:w-1],%[fx:h-1] line %[fx:w-1],0 0,%[fx:h-1]" -alpha off \
-fill "graya(50%,0.25)" \
-strokewidth 1 -stroke "graya(100%,0.25)" \
-gravity center -font arial -pointsize 48 \
-annotate +0+0 "Hello World" tile_aqua_500_text_x.jpg
```

Result of either command:

[image]

Comment: Hi fmw42, thank you, I've done the coding using your cli. I am wondering how can I add a bottom white area with text to include website address like shutterstock.com?

Comment: Do you want to add the white area inside the image bound or appended to the bottom of the image?

Comment: Hi fmw42, I want to add the white area inside the image bound ( because all my drawings stored in database has width and height, change them will cause potential bugs)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would create a watermark mask with the text effect, and composite over the source image.

**Step 1: Create text effect for reuse**

```
convert -pointsize 64 -font GeorgiaB \
        -fill black -stroke white -strokewidth 2 \
        -background transparent -channel A -evaluate subtract 75% \
        caption:"Hello World" mask.png
```

[image: mask.png]

**Step 2: Composite text effect over other images**

```
convert -size 500x400 plasma: mask.png \
        -gravity center -compose ATop  -composite output.png
```

[image: output.png]

There's a lot more examples of text handling & effects, as well as composite techniques over @ [Anthony's Usage documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/).

Comment: Hi emcconville, thank you :) How can I add a big X like shutterstock.com?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to add a white area at the bottom with text. This is one. If that is not what you want, then please explain further.

```
infile="tile_aqua_500.jpg"
ww=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:w-1]" info:)
hh=$(convert -ping "$infile" -format "%[fx:h-1]" info:)
convert "$infile" \
-fill "graya(100%,0.75)" \
-draw "line 0,0 $ww,$hh line $ww,0 0,$hh" -alpha off \
-fill "graya(50%,0.25)" \
-strokewidth 1 -stroke "graya(100%,0.25)" \
-gravity center -font arial -pointsize 48 \
-annotate +0+0 "Hello World" \
-undercolor white -gravity southeast -pointsize 24 \
-fill black -annotate +10+10 "yourdomain.com" \
tile_aqua_500_text_x_text.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: If my answers have helped, please consider giving them an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate method to the excellent one from `emcconville` using Imagemagick -annotate to draw text directly on an image. I start with a small tillable image that I enlarge to 500x500 in size, before drawing the text with 50% transparency in mid gray and with a 50% transparent white outline. You can change the shades of gray and transparency as desired along with the font and pint-size. Change +0+0 to shift the locations of the text relative to the gravity center. Change -gravity to other compass locations to draw the text relative to those locations.

```
convert -size 500x500 tile:tile_aqua.jpg \
-fill "graya(50%,0.5)" -strokewidth 1 -stroke "graya(100%,0.5)" \
-gravity center -font arial -pointsize 64 \
-annotate +0+0 "Hello World" result.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert -size 500x500 tile:tile_aqua.jpg \
-fill "graya(50%,0.25)" -strokewidth 1 -stroke "graya(100%,0.25)" \
-gravity southeast -font arial -pointsize 48 \
-annotate +50+50 "Hello World" result1.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Hi fmw42, thank you :) How can I add a big X like shutterstock.com?